# Efecto de imagen que cambia cuando mueves un scroll vertizal por encima de ella

Tags: javascript, html5, scroll, slider

Tengo un proyecto en mente y he estado intentando buscar cómo hacer el efecto de, por ejemplo, el antes y el después de un cambio visual en un producto/juego. Un panel con una barra vertical en el centro que según la mueves para un lado u otro, cambia el contenido del panel (sea imagen o vídeo). Para ilustrarlo un poco, dejo un ejemplo en esta web, donde nada más entrar se ve el efecto que me gustaría saber hacer o al menos saber buscar, porque no sé muy bien cómo definirlo para buscarlo

Aquí la web: https://www.ageofempires.com/games/aoe/

He visto el onscroll, pero no sé si con eso se puede conseguir

Gracias de antemano ^^

Comment: Quería decir que la propia barra de scroll es vertical pero se mueve de manera horizontal, fallo en el título, perdonad

Comment: Una vez más, la ayuda del inspeccionar elemento de las herramientas de Desarrollador de nuestro navegador es indispensable. En la página que estás usando de ejemplo cuando mueves a un lado y a otro la barra aparece en juego la clase *draggable*. Esta clase pertenece a una librería de Jquery que se llama **Jquery UI** que entre otras funcionalidades te da acceso a un sistema de Drag & Drop. Investiga su funcionamiento porque ahí tienes la clave.

Comment: @PHPMyguel estaba investigando elemento, pero no me fijé en el draggable porque no lo moví para ver qué pasaba en el movimiento. Tienes razón, ahí estaba la clave. Muchas gracias por la respuesta, con eso lo tengo ya enfocado y puedo buscarlo

Siento no haber recurrido a ello antes, pero me cegué intentándolo buscar en lugar de hacer la obviedad de inspeccionar elemento xD

Comment: Mira la librería [ScrollMagic](http://scrollmagic.io/)

Comment: Vaya, he mirado la librería y me viene genial tanto para esto como para otros efectos en scroll que quería usar para una web. Muchísimas gracias @JuanSalvadorPortugal :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que buscas es un [Image Comparison Slider](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_image_comparison.asp) (pulsa ejecutar para ver el efecto):

```js
function initComparisons() {
  var x, i;
  /* Find all elements with an "overlay" class: */
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("img-comp-overlay");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    /* Once for each "overlay" element:
    pass the "overlay" element as a parameter when executing the compareImages function: */
    compareImages(x[i]);
  }
  function compareImages(img) {
    var slider, img, clicked = 0, w, h;
    /* Get the width and height of the img element */
    w = img.offsetWidth;
    h = img.offsetHeight;
    /* Set the width of the img element to 50%: */
    img.style.width = (w / 2) + "px";
    /* Create slider: */
    slider = document.createElement("DIV");
    slider.setAttribute("class", "img-comp-slider");
    /* Insert slider */
    img.parentElement.insertBefore(slider, img);
    /* Position the slider in the middle: */
    slider.style.top = (h / 2) - (slider.offsetHeight / 2) + "px";
    slider.style.left = (w / 2) - (slider.offsetWidth / 2) + "px";
    /* Execute a function when the mouse button is pressed: */
    slider.addEventListener("mousedown", slideReady);
    /* And another function when the mouse button is released: */
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", slideFinish);
    /* Or touched (for touch screens: */
    slider.addEventListener("touchstart", slideReady);
     /* And released (for touch screens: */
    window.addEventListener("touchstop", slideFinish);
    function slideReady(e) {
      /* Prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image: */
      e.preventDefault();
      /* The slider is now clicked and ready to move: */
      clicked = 1;
      /* Execute a function when the slider is moved: */
      window.addEventListener("mousemove", slideMove);
      window.addEventListener("touchmove", slideMove);
    }
    function slideFinish() {
      /* The slider is no longer clicked: */
      clicked = 0;
    }
    function slideMove(e) {
      var pos;
      /* If the slider is no longer clicked, exit this function: */
      if (clicked == 0) return false;
      /* Get the cursor's x position: */
      pos = getCursorPos(e)
      /* Prevent the slider from being positioned outside the image: */
      if (pos < 0) pos = 0;
      if (pos > w) pos = w;
      /* Execute a function that will resize the overlay image according to the cursor: */
      slide(pos);
    }
    function getCursorPos(e) {
      var a, x = 0;
      e = e || window.event;
      /* Get the x positions of the image: */
      a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
      /* Calculate the cursor's x coordinate, relative to the image: */
      x = e.pageX - a.left;
      /* Consider any page scrolling: */
      x = x - window.pageXOffset;
      return x;
    }
    function slide(x) {
      /* Resize the image: */
      img.style.width = x + "px";
      /* Position the slider: */
      slider.style.left = img.offsetWidth - (slider.offsetWidth / 2) + "px";
    }
  }
}

initComparisons();
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.img-comp-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px; /*should be the same height as the images*/
}

.img-comp-img {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-comp-img img {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.img-comp-slider {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  cursor: ew-resize;
  /*set the appearance of the slider:*/
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  opacity: 0.7;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-comp-container">
  <div class="img-comp-img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200/" width="300" height="200">
  </div>
  <div class="img-comp-img img-comp-overlay">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200/?random" width="300" height="200">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no sabía que estaba en w3c... estaba tonto cuando lo pregunté. Con vuestros comentarios tengo material de sobra :)

PD: no puedo marcar como respuesta ni votar porque stack parece que no me quiere aquí y por mucho que "Termine el registro para mi cuenta" me sigue saliendo el mensaje y no se confirma ni se crea la cuenta ni nada